# Bind DNS doesn't start, error as file not found; after a /usr/sbin command it works

Tags: centos, bind

I get a strange error whenever I restart the server.

Bind doesn't autostart or start. I get the following error when I do `service named start`:

```
 _default/0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: file not found
```

After I do `/usr/sbin/named -u named` it works.

How can I make bind autostart without the error?

Answer (score 0):

Error has been fixed.

Simply copy the `0.168.192.rev` file from `/var/named` to `/var/named/chroot/var/named` also.

Comment: It shouldn't be a matter of "also", rather that the file needs to exist in the one location that you are actually using. If it worked when you started it manually with `/usr/sbin/named -u named` command, I would have to assume that you were normally starting it with `-t /var/named/chroot` and that removing the `-t /my/chroot/path` option was what made the difference.